# WebGL viewer using Three.js + ColladaLoader.js

Tags: javascript, three.js, collada

I am using the following code to implement WebGL viewer:

```
            var scene = new THREE.Scene();
                    var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(100, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);
                    var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
                    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
                    document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
                    camera.position.set(0, 4, 0);
                    var loader = new THREE.ColladaLoader();
                    loader.load("b.dae", function (result) {
                        scene.add(result.scene);
                        render();
                    });
                    var light = new THREE.AmbientLight( 0x404040 );
                    scene.add( light );
                    function render() {
                        requestAnimationFrame(render);
                        renderer.render(scene, camera);
                    }
```

But when I load the my own model using colladaloader, there's a error message:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'input' of null

And I find that error occur on this line in ColladaLoader.js

`var vertexData = sources[ this.vertices.input['POSITION'].source ].data;`

I don't know is this a problem in my model?
I use SketchUp to create the model and export to .dae format.